# Android SQLite Virtual Table ID value not auto incrementing, returning null

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got an SQLite Virtual Table that I realized isn't auto incrementing the _id parameter, instead filling the value as null repeatedly.

Here is my code for the table

```
// Chat History Table
    public static String ID = "_id";
    public static String MESSAGE = "message";
    public static String BUSINESS = "business";
    public static String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static String FROMTO = "fromto";
    public static String READ = "read";
    public static String LOGGED = "logged";
    public static String AGENT = "agent_id";
    public static String AGENT_NAME = "agent_name";

    // Logging Values
    public static int LOG_SENDING = 2;
    public static int LOG_SENT = 1;
    public static int LOG_FAILED = 0;

    public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE
            + " USING fts3 (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY AUTOINCREMENT, " + READ
            + ", " + BUSINESS + ", " + MESSAGE + ", " + TIMESTAMP + ", "
            + AGENT_NAME + ", " + AGENT + ", " + LOGGED + ", " + FROMTO + ")";
```

The Log message of the cursor to check what is being returned

> 04-16 23:53:17.612: D/MessagingActivity(6313): timestamp=1397672593064
>   message=I know _id=null fromto=0 read=0 logged=null agent_id=null
>   agent_name=Aakrit business=55

The logged and agent_id being null is by design, but the id isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your column **_id** that represents unique identificator of each row. **FTS3 tables** have special column (it's hidden) called **rowid** and you should use that column instead of **_id** column to get row's identificator.

So you can try this:

```
select rowid, * from YourTable
```

and now it should return correct id value and not null as before. Here is [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). 
Hope, it'll solve your problem you're facing.